# How can I get my function to go back to a certain point in code after elif statement?

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I'm trying to get user input for adding persons details to a dictionary, after they go through the first while loop. It asks them if they would like to add another entry, if the user enters anything other than "y" or "n" I want it to say ivalid entry, and ask them again, if they then enter "y" or "n" I would like it to go back to the start of the while loop again.

Tried changing the code, the loops and the if, elif and else statements but can't figure it out.

```
import pprint


everyone = {}

def people_database():
    yesno = "y"
    while yesno == "y":
        name = input("What is the name you would like to add?: ")
        age = input("What is the age you would like to add?: ")
        residence = input("What is the residence you would like to add?: ")
        everyone["people"] = {"Name": name,
                              "Age": age,
                              "Residence": residence}
        yesno = input("Would you like to add another? Enter y or n: ")
        if yesno == "y" or yesno == "Y":
            continue
        elif yesno == "n" or yesno == "N":
            break
        else:
            while yesno != "y" or yesno != "Y" or yesno != "n" or yesno != "N":
                print("Not a valid input.")
                yesno = input("Would you like to add another? Enter y or n: ")
                if yesno == "y" or yesno == "Y":
                    continue
                elif yesno == "n" or yesno == "N":
                    break

people_database()
```

If after entering wrong entry they then input correct entry the function should start again.

Comment: you have no choice but to add a flag in the inner loop and check it in the while condition. if you would split your script to function it wouldn't be too difficult

Comment: @OmerBenHaim Absolutely no need for a flag! At least the way I understand the question. In fact, the whole `yesno` variable is redundant if the use is this simple.

Comment: we can talk a lot about improving this code to make it a lot more readable but for what he wanted to do there is no way i know. (stop an outer loop from inside an inner loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be very beneficial to construct a function for recieving the yes / no input. But in my opinion it need not be recursive in contrast to liamhawkins' answer. A simple while loop would suffice. And no need to print any error statement, as it is pretty obvious to the user that something went wrong if the question is posed again with clear instructions how to answer.

```
def get_decision(question: str='y/n: '):
    ans = ''
    while ans not in ['y', 'n']:
        ans = input(question)
    return ans

everyone = {}


def people_database():
    while True:
        name = input("What is the name you would like to add?: ")
        age = input("What is the age you would like to add?: ")
        residence = input("What is the residence you would like to add?: ")
        everyone["people"] = {"Name": name,
                              "Age": age,
                              "Residence": residence}

        if get_decision('Would you like to add another? Enter y or n: ') == 'n':
            break

people_database()
```

You can of course extend the list of accepted answers and make the decision condition more complex accordingly, but this is a minimal example. In my opinion accepting only one symbol for a particular action is clearer than guessing what the user ment, although in this case it is pretty unambiguous.

---

Side note, I don't know the full story behind your case, but it seems that overriding the `people` key in the dictionary is not useful in the loop. You'd probably want an incrementing ID to mimic a "database":

```
people = {}


def people_database():
    person_id = 0
    while True:
        name = input('Name?: ')
        age = input('Age?: ')
        residence = input('Residence?: ')

        people[person_id] = {
            'Name': name,
            'Age': age,
            'Residence': residence
        }

        if get_decision('Would you like to add another? Enter y or n: ') == 'n':
            break

        person_id += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    people_database()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second while loop is testing whether `yesno` is not `y` **or** not `Y` **or** not `n` **or** not `N`. It will always run, because it can't be all of these cases at the same time. Change your `or`s to `and`s

Also, your first while loop should also check for uppercase Y.

Comment: I think it would be better to simply force `yesno` to the desired format for checking straight after it is input.  e.g.: `yesno = input("promtpt> ").strip().lower()[0]`